# NuGet Package restore failed for project PROJECT: Unable to find version 2.0.0 of package 'Microsoft.Net.Compilers'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, nuget-package-restore

I used the GitHub extension of Visual Studio 2015 to clone my project onto a new computer. I try to restore packages and I get an error that says:

```
NuGet Package restore failed for project PROJECT: Unable to find version 2.0.0 of package 'Microsoft.Net.Compilers'
```

I've looked into some other questions about similar issues, but none of those solutions have worked for me yet.

I tried deleting the packages folder, opening up up Visual Studios again and then rebuilding. That didn't resolve it.

I tried manually installing Microsoft.Net.Compilers in Package Manager Console.

```
 PM> Install-Package Microsoft.Net.Compilers
```

I tried removing this bit of code from the csproj file (this seemed to work for some):

```
    <Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Error Condition="!Exists('$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets'))" />
</Target>
```

I tried reinstalling all packages with

```
Update-Package –reinstall
```

So far I haven't had any luck resolving the issue. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

```
I tried the response below and received this error:

Install-Package : Some NuGet packages are missing from the solution. The packages need to be restored in order to build the dependency graph. Restore the packages before performing any operations.
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  -Id Microsoft.Net.Compilers -Version 1.3.2 -Source nuget.org
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetMissingPackages,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
```

It also prompted me to restore packages. When I hit restore, I got the same error as usual.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Based on your error message looks like you are looking for a version that no longer exists and cannot tell which Package source you have selected. I feel like you are looking for version 2.0.0 which is not available in nuget.org repository. The latest one is 2.0.0-rc and it is pre release candidate.

Please try this command if you want to get the latest version

```
Install-Package -Id Microsoft.Net.Compilers -Version 2.0.0-rc -Source nuget.org
```

If you want the latest stable version (1.3.2), try this command

```
Install-Package -Id Microsoft.Net.Compilers -Version 1.3.2 -Source nuget.org
```

**UPDATE**
If the package still cannot be installed, then that package may be out of sync between packages.config, packages/ folder and .csproj file

Please follow these steps to perform manual cleanup

1. Close visual studio.
2. Open .csproj in a notepad or some text editor and manually remove all entries related to Microsoft.Net.Compilers
3. Open packages.config in a notepad or some text editor and  and remove entry for the Microsoft.Net.Compilers package
4. Go to packages/ folder in windows explorer and delete the Microsoft.Net.Compilers folder
5. Now start the visual studio and open the solution.
6. Now try to install the package again.

Some of the entries that you may have to remove from .csproj as part of step 2 are these

```
<Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.3.2\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.3.2\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props')" />

<NuGetPackageImportStamp></NuGetPackageImportStamp>

<Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
        <PropertyGroup>
          <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
        </PropertyGroup>
        <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.3.2\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.3.2\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props'))" />
</Target>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried both of those and each time I got this error: Install-Package : Some NuGet packages are missing from the solution. The packages need to be restored in order to build the dependency graph. Restore the packages before performing any operations.
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  -Id Microsoft.Net.Compilers -Version 1.3.2 -Source nuget.org
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetMissingPackages,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Comment: Please see my update. Looks like your Microsoft.Net.Compilers package  may be out of sync between packages.config, packages/ folder and .csproj file. You have to manually clean it up before attempting to install again.

Answer (score 23):

I had a similar error after a clean install of Visual Studio 2017 and had to do the following to get it to automatically restore missing NuGet packages successfully.  In VS, go to "Tools > Options > NuGet Package Manager > Package Sources", and ensure the appropriate package sources show and are checked.

See screen shot below.  The addition of the nuget.org package source at the top tells VS to go online to download the packages from NuGet if it can’t find the appropriate versions on the local machine.

**Update (8/2023)**: Per comments below, nowadays the appropriate package source URL for NuGet is https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.

[image]

Comment: Just FYI for others: Mine had the source of Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages and that path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\" didn't have the NuGet pkgs listed in the project. Had to add a new package source with path - "https://api.nuget.org/v3-index/index.json" and then restoring Nuget pkgs or rebuild worked.

Comment: Yep, same as @ShivaNaru, only local path in my VS installation on new machine. Unbelievable that one needs to find this setting before nuget is enabled. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio#package-sources

Answer (score 3):

I also had similar problem on VS 2019, this one worked for me, just go to Tools > Options > NuGet Package Manager > General and Clear all NuGet Cache.

See the image below
[image: See the image below]

Answer (score 2):

This might be a bit late but it will still help somebody. When you try to check in your code and you get this kind of an error, it means that you had the package installed and uninstalled it again, so you just need to locate the package under included changes, in my example i an using TFS, and exclude or undo. this will solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I moved my project in relation to where the NuGet packages had originally been stored in my project, and I eventually discovered that this causes a problem with that `.csproj` file that might not be immediately obvious.

Following the move and after doing a NuGet Package Restore, a second entry had been added to the `EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports` target of my `.csproj` file reflecting the relative path of the new location.

The target now looked like the following:

```
  <Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.10.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.10.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props'))" />
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.10.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.10.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props'))" />
  </Target>
```

Notice the two entries, with different paths to where the `packages` were located. This meant one of them (the first one, which was from before I moved the project) would always fail.

The fix was simple enough. I just removed the first `Error` node from the `Target`.

I also found that there was a similar problem in the initial `Import` nodes of the root `Project` node.

I had the following:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="..\..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.10.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props" Condition="Exists('..\..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.10.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props')" />
  <Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.10.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.10.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props')" />
```

Again, the fix was just to remove the erroneous `Import` node.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of error can happen also using an old version of nuget.exe. For example, if you download the agent.zip of TFS 2015, inside it has version 3.2.1:

\Agent\Worker\Tools\nuget.exe

That version can give the error "Unable to find version '3.7.1' of package 'NUnit'." with a solution created with VS 2015. (NUnit3TestAdapter.3.9.0 doesn't give error, though)

Updating nuget.exe to 5.2 solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I know why, it's in the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages` folder. There are packages that you have installed before.

Answer (score 0):

This was my error:  "The project references NuGet packages that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them."

[image]

And this was my solution:  I had to make sure that my Package Sources were checked in the Manage Nuget Packages window.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

go to tools in navbar and tools and features and chek your freamworks are downloaded or not
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUzv7.png)

Comment: Please fix typos in your answer

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30623131)